# Question related to pronoun and articles

Tags: grammar, articles, pronouns, relative-pronouns, learning

Which relative pronoun is used for anyone and someone, Who or that?

In my grammar book it is written to use "that" after the words like all, same, any, none, nothing.

One more question.

The question I asked above I used definite article "the" with "words" which is a plural countable noun. Rule says articles are omitted before plural countable nouns. But, here "the words" refer to some particular words (all, same, any, none, nothing). Is the usage of "the" correct here?

Comment: (1) Depending on the context, style, and choice, you can use either relative pronoun for a person. (2) That rule is wrong—or at least only partially stated.

Comment: "the words" is correct if it refers to some particular words?

Comment: *The words you entered are wrong.*

Answer (score 0):

To work out the pronoun you may benefit by trying it in reverse.
Write the sentence without the *anyone/someone* modifier and see what is needed afterwords.

"I brought the donuts for one/those *who* might enjoy one or ten."

This will give you an idea of what you were intending. Then you can modify *Who* or *That* as you see fit.

"I brought the donuts for [anyone] *who* might enjoy one or ten."

Either will do as it is truly a matter of context, style, and choice, says JB.